# How to create opacity mask from colored bitmap?

Tags: unreal-4, maps, unreal, color, masking

For the image (bitmap) below,

[image]

if I do:

1. Create a spite with the image in unreal engine.
2. Create a opacity mask on the spite.
3. Use this image, choose a specific color, such as blue, make its corresponding region the only opacity region on the mask.

My question is about the implementation of part 2 and part 3 in Unreal engine, they are quite confusing.

> If anyone know how to implement it in unity, it would also be helpful.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: It's unclear to me whether you're looking for a solution in Unreal (as described in your tags and step 1), or in Unity (as mentioned in your closing remark). Which is it?

Comment: I am looking for solution in Unreal, but if anyone can solve in unity, it could be a way to think about in Unreal.